# Upgrade xubuntu from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 14.10

I set `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version` to `For any new version`. Then I did this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And nothing happened. The result of `cat /etc/lsb-release` is `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Screenshot:

[image: terminal screenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Procedure:

First: You need to update the system.(You already did)

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot your system to finish installing updates, and to upgrade to new available version:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
update-manager -d
```

Software Updater will show up and search for the new release, after a few seconds, you will see a screen like below that saying:

However, Ubuntu 14.10 is available now (you have 14.04).

Press the button Upgrade to start upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10.

[image]

The Software Updater will ask you to confirm still you want to upgrade, press Start Upgrade to begin installing Ubuntu 14.10.

Now, the Software Updater will prepare to start setting up new software channels, and after a few minutes, the software updater will notify you the details the number of packages are going to be removed, and number of packages are going to be installed, press Start upgrade to continue.

Ended the dist-upgrade, reboot your system and:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: I had to first change from `never` to `for any new version` in update-manager updates `notify my of a new ubuntu version`.

Answer (score 2):

The process suggested in [this source](http://optinux.com/utopic-unicorn-ubuntu-14-10-released/) is easier than the accepted answer:

---

*To upgrade on a desktop system:*

- Press Alt+F2 and type in `update-manager` into the command box.
- Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release ‘14.10’ is available.
- Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

To upgrade on a server system:

- Install the `update-manager-core` package if it is not already installed.
- Launch the upgrade tool with the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` (or with `-d` option if it complains no new version found).
- Follow the on-screen instructions.

---

Comment: No.  My update manager shows me a lot of things to update, but it does not say "new 14.10 is available". And I do not dare to _first_ do these updates and then to hope that an upgrade to 14.10 is offered.

Comment: **EDIT** No.  My update manager shows me a lot of things to update, but it does not say "new 14.10 is available". These are just the normal updates that would appear ith apt-get update/upgrade. I think if you have missed once the initial question whether you want to upgrade to 14.10, you will never be asked again.